# Cant use Apply with data table

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which I read into R in the following way

```
morbiditydata <-fread("data.csv", nrows=502647, select=c(2458:2486))
```

I then want to make a new column called "hypertens" where it is "1" if any of the columns (28 of them) in the imported data are equal to "1065" or "1072", and 0 otherwise.  Thus I have used:

```
morbiditydata$hypertens<-apply(morbiditydata[,c(1:28)], MARGIN=1, function(x) {ifelse(x==1065 | x==1072, "1","0")})
```

However this produces the error

> dim(X) must have a positive length

How do I work around this?

If it helps, this will produce a similar table:

```
a=c(1, 1, 1065, 1072, 9999, 0)

b=c(1, 1065, 1065, 1072, 0, 9999)

c=c(9999, 1065, 1072, 1072, 0, 1)

df=data.frame(a, b, c)
```

Comment: It is a `data.table`.  Use `morbiditydata[,1:28, with = FALSE]` to subset the columns.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
 nm1 <- names(morbiditydata)[1:28]
 morbiditydata[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
      as.integer(x %in% c(1065, 1072))), .SDcols = nm1]
```

---

Regarding the error in OP's code, the columns in `data.table` are subsetted using `with=FALSE` when using numeric indices, i.e.

```
 t(apply(morbiditydata[,1:28, with = FALSE], 1, 
      function(x) {ifelse(x==1065 | x==1072, "1","0")}))
```

---

Using the OP's example 'df'

```
 nm1 <- names(df)[1:2]
 setDT(df)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x)
       as.integer(x %in% c(1065, 1072)))  ,.SDcols = nm1]
 df
#   a b    c
#1: 0 0 9999
#2: 0 1 1065
#3: 1 1 1072
#4: 1 1 1072
#5: 0 0    0
#6: 0 0    1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
morbiditydata <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(c(1065, 
      1072, 1:5), 5*30, replace=TRUE), ncol=30))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  However when I use

 apply(morbiditydata[,1:28, with = FALSE], 1, 
      function(x) {ifelse(x==1065 | x==1072, "1","0")})

it says:

Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  502647 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector
2: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 14074116 items to be assigned to 502647 items of column 'hypertens' (13571469 unused)

and puts 1s and 0s in incorrect places

Comment: @RossM  I also posted an example dataset as you haven't shown any.

Comment: I tried it on your data and, for me, it returned the same errors as before:
 Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  5 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector
2: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 140 items to be assigned to 5 items of column 'add1' (135 unused)